# preg_replace : how get what is replaced

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I want to show cards from regex codes :
ah displays As of hearts,
kc displays King of clubs
...

I used preg_replace() to do that in this way :

```
$arr = array('ah', 'kh', 'qh', ..., '3c', '2c');
$regex = '';
foreach ($arr as $i => $card)
{
    $regex .= $card;
    if ($i < count($arr) - 1)
        $regex .= '|';
}

$message = preg_replace('#('.$regex.')#', '<img src="'.$dontknow.'.png" class="card" alt="" />', $message);
```

I don't know what value put in the src attribute, I want to tell to preg_replace() "when you find 'ah' you put ah.png, if it's kc then $dontknow == 'kc' etc.

Someone could be bring me some help ?

Comment: This seems like an overkill solution.  Is the value of `$message` so complex that a regex is required to get the card code?

Comment: You can construct `$regex = '#'.join('|',$arr).'#';` and avoid the `foreach` loop. -- But I just noticed, your REGEXP is likely to change all sorts of occurences in your message: a string like 'ah' is not very specific and might occur in places where you would not want the playing card shown.

Comment: Thank you, yes I know and it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$message = preg_replace('#('.$regex.')#', 
                          '<img src="$1.png" class="card" alt="" />', $message);
```

Comment: I don't get it, it was my solution, what is $regex for you ? If it's the array, it's not working

Comment: You can use `$1.png` for your image source

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see your message

Answer (score 1):

Use $1 reference - it is a link to a first group that PHP matched through preg_replace

Comment: Perfect, thanks. We can specify we had to use it like a string :  `'<img src="$1" ... />'` and NOT LIKE `'<img src="'.$1.'.png" ... />'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `for` loop. Here's a slightly improved version with the correct regex.

```
$arr = array('ah', 'kh', 'qh', ..., '3c', '2c');

$message = preg_replace('/('. implode('|'. $regex) .')/is', '<img src="$1.png" class="card" alt="" />', $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `$n` in your replacement to reference to a certain matching group (`n` is a number).

Since we pulled out the big guns:

- Let's use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape regex reserved characters in your array
- PHP has a great set of function to juggle with arrays, let's use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) instead of that ugly loop
- [From the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058920/preg-replace-how-get-what-is-replaced#comment26424010_18058920), I realised that you need to add word boundaries `\b` to prevent false matches like `yeah` being replaced to `ye<img...>`. See this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH5aZ7)

**Code:**

```
$message = 'foo qh bar';
$arr = array('ah', 'kh', 'qh', '3c', '2c');

$escaped_arr = array_map(function($v){
    return preg_quote($v, '#');
}, $arr); // Anonymous function requires PHP 5.3+

$message = preg_replace('#\b('.implode('|', $escaped_arr).')\b#', '<img src="$1.png" class="card" alt="" />', $message);

echo $message;
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/40715)

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your 'markers' indicating the playing cards, by adding a special character (like `@` in the following example) to them. This will protect you from inadvertently changing other text passages:

```
$arr = array('ah', 'kh', 'qh', 'ac', '3c', '2c');
$txt = 'This is a line with cards @ah and @qh but with a potential head-ache.'; 
$rx = '#@('.join('|',$arr).')#';
echo preg_replace($rx,"<img src=$1.jpg>",$txt);
```

Comment: It's a good idea but I'm looking for speed, the message is not a text, I think you get it q: